# Regex Unable to exclude a string

Tags: regex

Here is my regex i want to exclude string `login_overlay` but i am unable to exclude that string from my regex it capture the `login` string and passes the regex:

`(^\/$|!login_overlay|login|welcome|register|password_forgot|terms|privacy|company_site|account_calendar|account_cancel|account_facebook|account_google|account_ical|account_language|account_outlook|account_password)`

What am i doing wrong is there something wrong with my regex condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead for that:

```
(?!.*?login_overlay)
```

[**`See Lookaround Tutorial`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks mate it helped me i will mark it correct when it will allow me

Comment: thanks again for the tutorial edit once again sir :)

Comment: Just did i was waiting for time limit to end

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude strings from regexes that easily.  Although if your regex implementation supports negative lookahead, you can get close:

```
  (^\/$|(?!login_overlay|something_else_excluded|...)(login|welcome|...))
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the concept it was really helping it means i can use negative look ahead to achieve my goal